Relativization of formulas with defined function symbols.
So I was trying to understand how to relativize formulas $\phi$ in $\{\in\}$ to some class $M$ in the language of set theory. It can be sone by following the recursive procedure below (from kunen): 
$(a)$ $(x = y)^{M}$ is $x = y$ 
$(b)$ $(x \in y)^{M}$ is $x \in y$ 
$(c)$ $(\psi_1 \land \psi_2)^M$ is $(\psi_1)^M\land(\psi_2)^M$ 
$(d)$ $(\neg \psi)^M$ is $\neg(\psi^M)$ 
$(e)$ $(\exists x\psi)^M$ is $\exists x(x \in M \land \psi^M)$
This seems all clear to me. After this I wanted to learn how to relativize formulas $\phi$ which has defined relations,constant or functions. Obviously we can just unabbreviate the formula and relativize that unabbreviated formula , but I would like relativize in a way so that we don't have to expand out the entire formula and I can just focus on the effect of relativization on the defined notions themselves. For defined relations it is pretty clear to me, but I am not sure about how to do it for defined functions. Kunen has some paragraphs on it but I felt like it was informal.
Can someone explain to me how to do it systematically for defined functions?

First, you should know that there are no function symbols in the standard language for set theory. Every function is added by definitional expansion.
It may answer your question (there is no function symbols, so the relativization is defined for every formula with no problem), but I am pretty sure you do not like it. What you want to ask would be how the relativization works for the definitional expansion. To see the answer, let us examine how the definitional expansion works.
For example, consider the 'function' $x\mapsto \{x\}$. It is defined by the formula
$$\phi(x,y)\iff x\in y\land \forall z\in y(z=x).$$
($\phi(x,y)$ states $y=\{x\}$.) Then every formula $\psi(x,\{x\})$ is an abbreviation of
$$\exists y \phi(x,y)\land \psi(x,y).$$
(Or $\forall y \phi(x,y)\to \psi(x,y)$. They are equivalent as long as $\phi(x,y)$ defines a function.) So the relativization $\phi(x,\{x\})^M$ is in fact
$$[\exists y \phi(x,y)\land \psi(x,y)]^M,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\exists y\in M [\phi^M(x,y)\land \psi^M(x,y)].$$
It is how we compute the relativization of a 'function.' I illustrated how it works in a specific example, but the same argument works in general.
But let me go a bit further, which should be important in a latter sections and chapters in Kunen's book you are reading.
Going back to the example, now if you know $M$ is transitive model of set theory, then $\phi^M(x,y)$ iff $\phi(x,y)$ since $\phi$ is a bounded formula. Hence we get
$$\exists y\in M [\phi(x,y)\land \psi^M(x,y)].$$
It is equivalent to $\psi^M(x,\{x\})$; That is, the relativization does not change the function. In general, if the function $F$ is $\Delta_0$-definable by a formula $\phi(x,y)$ (like $x\mapsto\{x\}$), $M$ is transitive, and $M$ knows $F$ is a function in the sense that $M\vDash\forall x\exists!y\phi(x,y)$, then $(\psi(F(x)))^M$ is $\psi^M(F(x))$.
